# UNION types double precision and character varying cannot be matched

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run a program from my following database
[DATABASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeQZd.png)

But i am getting the error "UNION types double precision and character varying cannot be matched" every time I try to run the program

My code is

```
SELECT   
    EXTRACT(YEAR 
            FROM AGE(users.dob)) AS Age, 
    users.gender,  
    app.name AS App 

FROM users
    LEFT OUTER JOIN app_user_profile
        ON users.id = app_user_profile.users_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN app
        ON app_user_profile.app_id = app.id

UNION

SELECT cities.name AS City, provinces.name AS Province, countries.name AS Country
FROM cities
LEFT OUTER JOIN provinces
    ON cities.country_id = provinces.country_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN countries
    ON provinces.country_id = countries.country_id
```

Comment: Read this [UNION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION) and it will become plain what the issue is.

Comment: That UNION makes absolutely no sense. The two data sets have nothing in common other than their number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

[UNION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION)s in PostgreSQL must have the same number of columns and the columns must be of "compatible data types".

Judging from the names of your columns, these seem to be totally different things that you want to UNION. Which is unusual, but it can be done. The biggest problem seems to be between Age and City which are a number and text/varchar, respectively. If you cast Age as text, the UNION should work.

```
SELECT   
    EXTRACT(YEAR 
            FROM AGE(users.dob))::text AS Age, 
    ....
```

Type casting can either be done with `Column::<new type>` or `Cast(Column, <new type>)`. The first version is a custom PostgreSQL syntax and easy to type, and the second version conforms to SQL standards.